# Why two bridged veth cannot ping each other?

Tags: networking, bridge, iproute, veth

I need to set up a network environment where two veth interfaces is attached to one bridge and they need to be able to communicate with each other.

So I execute the following commands in a clean ubuntu shell:

```
# Create Two veth and attach them to the bridge
sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth0p
sudo ip link add veth1 type veth peer name veth1p
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 veth0p
sudo brctl addif br0 veth1p

# Set links up
sudo ip link set veth0 up
sudo ip link set veth1 up
sudo ip link set veth0p up
sudo ip link set veth1p up
sudo ip link set br0 up

# Give each veth an IP address
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev veth0
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev veth1

# Try to ping one from the other
ping 10.0.0.1 -I veth1
```

The ping does not work. Could anyone help me on this? What should I do to make `veth0` and `veth2` being able to ping each other?

The output of the `ip r s` is:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.119 metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev veth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
10.0.0.0/24 dev veth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 
192.168.0.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.119 
192.168.0.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.119 metric 100
```

The purpose of this is to put those two `veth` interfaces into a VXLAN overlay network later. But for development purpose, I want to test the bridge and the two interfaces without the VXLAN been set up at this point. (But even though there is no VXLAN set up, they should be able to ping each other as long as they are on the same bridge right?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Routing is supposed to happen between multiple systems, each having its own network stack: between multiple network stacks.

There is no interest in making this test work on a *single* network stack. Getting it work like this requires many tweaks, and the end result will not reflect at all a configuration similar to the intended goal and will not be useful to develop such project.

### The simplest correct way to do this on Linux is to use network namespaces (or containers)

Use OP's settings, then interfaces are moved to two namespaces (created using [`ip netns add`](https://manpages.debian.org/ip-netns.8)). As this triggers loss of configuration on interfaces, re-add what's missing. So as *root* user, after OP's setup (minus address assignments which will be lost anyway):

```
ip netns add system1
ip netns add system2

ip link set dev veth0 netns system1
ip link set dev veth1 netns system2

ip -n system1 link set lo up # this is optional for this problem
ip -n system2 link set lo up # this is optional for this problem
ip -n system1 address add 10.0.0.1/24 dev veth0
ip -n system2 address add 10.0.0.2/24 dev veth1
ip -n system1 link set dev veth0 up
ip -n system2 link set dev veth1 up
```

Now everything is simple. *system1* and *system2* simulate systems as they would be used in the real final setup. Command below will succeed and follow a normal routing behavior, as could be expected with real systems through a switch:

```
ip netns exec system1 ping 10.0.0.2
```

Note: this whole specific setup (with two peers only) can be shorted without bridge by initially creating the interfaces like this: `ip link add name veth0 type veth peer name veth1`. The bridge isn't part of the problem, but is most certainly needed as soon as a 3rd peer system has to be simulated.

---

### Bonus for the curious: answer the question to the letter

Goal: have the host ping itself over the wire instead of over the `lo` interface. Again, as a warning, even if this works, the result can't be used for anything useful, including for simulating multiple systems.

So this is done with OP's initial setup, without network namespace.

With a *single* network stack several tweaks must be done. There are a lot of details below, because these details got in the way to get it working correctly.

- system must [accept receiving a packet with a source IP address belonging to itself](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.10#n1395) instead of dropping it

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.veth0.accept_local=1
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.veth1.accept_local=1
  ```
- the same packet is seen twice, once when emitted, once when received back and this requires different (policy based) routes for the two cases.

  The system must distinguish the case where the packet is locally created and sent through `veth0` from the case where this packet is then received from `veth1`, over the wire. This requires two different routing tables selected by two different policy routing rules. With the reverse direction this would make a total of 4 rules and 4 tables. Actually the *local* routing table already include half of these (for received packets: intended for the host), so only locally emitted packets need a special routing rule and table.

  Policy rules:

  ```
  ip rule add priority 11 iif lo from 10.0.0.1 lookup 1001
  ip rule add priority 21 iif lo from 10.0.0.2 lookup 2001
  ```

  The special `iif lo` means locally initiated traffic (it's not really about receiving from the `lo` interface).

  And the associated routing tables each with its single route:

  ```
  ip route add 10.0.0.2 dev veth0 table 1001
  ip route add 10.0.0.1 dev veth1 table 2001
  ```
- the *local* routing table is in the way

  So far we have:

  ```
  # ip rule
  0:      from all lookup local
  11:     from 10.0.0.1 iif lo lookup 1001
  21:     from 10.0.0.2 iif lo lookup 2001
  32766:  from all lookup main
  32767:  from all lookup default

  # ip route show table local to root 10.0.0.0/24
  local 10.0.0.1 dev veth0 proto kernel scope host src 10.0.0.1 
  local 10.0.0.2 dev veth1 proto kernel scope host src 10.0.0.2 
  broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev veth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
  broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev veth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
  ```

  The *local* table has the lowest priority value rule and is used first. The two first entries match first and override the additional rules (prio 11 and 21) and routes, keeping the packet local (ie: using the `lo` interface).

  One could remove these entries, but then as written above, they are actually needed, but only after the added policy rules. Beside, changing addresses on interfaces would make the kernel add them back sooner or later.

  So instead, one can move the `from all lookup local` rule to a higher priority value leaving the added rules with priority 11 and 21 traversed first to get the special routes first:

  ```
  ip rule add priority 50 lookup local 
  ip rule del priority 0
  ```

One can check the routes that would follow a single ping and its answer:

The initial packet is

- either forced through `veth0` when using `ping -I veth0 10.0.0.2`:

  ```
  # ip route get oif veth0 to 10.0.0.2
  10.0.0.2 dev veth0 src 10.0.0.1 uid 0 
      cache
  ```
- or has its source IP address bound to 10.0.0.1 when using `ping -I 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2`:

  ```
  # ip route get from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.2
  10.0.0.2 from 10.0.0.1 dev veth0 table 1001 uid 0 
      cache
  ```

Both cases are routed the same (though using a different routing table).

This packet (traverses the bridge (see caveat later about ARP) and) is now received on the other side on `veth1`:

```
# ip route get from 10.0.0.1 iif veth1 to 10.0.0.2
local 10.0.0.2 from 10.0.0.1 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif veth1
```

The reply is sent back with source address 10.0.0.2 to destination 10.0.0.1:

```
# ip route get from 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.1
10.0.0.1 from 10.0.0.2 dev veth1 table 2001 uid 0 
    cache
```

and the reply (traverses the bridge and) is received on `veth0`:

```
# ip route get from 10.0.0.2 iif veth0 to 10.0.0.1
local 10.0.0.1 from 10.0.0.2 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif veth0
```

Ping round expected to successfully complete.

ARP requests are made and resolved:

```
# ip neigh
10.0.0.1 dev veth1 lladdr f2:2a:75:82:17:d3 DELAY
10.0.0.2 dev veth0 lladdr 42:91:a1:a6:64:45 REACHABLE
10.0.0.1 dev br0 lladdr f2:2a:75:82:17:d3 STALE
```

As can be seen, the bridge self interface `br0`, despite having no address configured participates in ARP and routing too by its mere presence in the same single network stack, because of Linux' implementation of Weak [host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model). Above `42:91:a1:a6:64:45` was from `br0` (inherited from `veth1p`). Because of this the first few pings can be initially routed as `veth0` -> `br0` (+ replies as `veth1` -> `veth0`) instead of `veth0` -> `veth1` (+ `veth1`-> `veth0`) and revert a few seconds later to the correct flow once the tentatively learnt ARP entries expire.

`br0` can be prevented from participating in routing by various means, among them:

- with [`arp_ignore`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.10#n1479):

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.br0.arp_ignore=1
  ```
- or by activating [`rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.10#n1407) (for [Strict Reverse Path Forwarding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3704#section-2.2)) on it so it won't reply ARP either:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.br0.rp_filter=1
  ```
- or isolating the bridge's self interface from the bridge ports if the Linux system supports bridge VLAN filtering:

  ```
  ip link set dev br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
  bridge vlan del vid 1 dev br0 self
  ```

  This detaches the bridge's self interface from communication with its own bridge ports in the default configuration, thus plugging the local network stack "leak" through it. (Also capturing with `tcpdump -i br0 -p` with the option `-p` to not set it in promiscuous mode won't receive any traffic anymore in this case).

Again this minor glitch would not happen in a real case, because the bridge would be elsewhere (eg: a real switch, an other VM or an other network namespace/container).